# Linux Web Kiosk

Tags: kernel

Hi I'm having a idea of develop a light weight Linux kernel which will boot and open a web browser in full screen and request data from pre define URL. Can any one give me some guides on this please.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi I'm having a idea of develop a light weight Linux kernel

It's not particularly heavy to start with -- a stock kernel with a minimal filesystem requires < 25 MB of RAM.  So don't worry about that part.

> which will boot and open a web browser in full screen and request data from pre define URL

You want to create a [kiosk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software), in other words.  There are various ways to do this, probably the easiest being the use of a distribution dedicated to such purpose, such as the [Fedora Kiosk spin](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/kiosk/).

It should be explained that **the kernel cannot execute a file browser** itself.  After the kernel boots, it loads a program called [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) and that then initializes the [userland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userspace#Userland) of the operating system.  Since a file browser is a  userland application, you *can* use the init system to accomplish this.  Exactly how that is done depends on which init system you are using, which depends upon which distribution you are using.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response , if I use kiosk isn't the GUI is also enable? Can't i display web request detail with out booting GUI?

Comment: No.  You can render graphics to the framebuffer without X, but I promise you will not find a web browser that does this.  If by "web request detail" you mean, e.g., the html source of a page or other textual data, sure, you can display unformatted text on a console.  There are also (non-graphical) console browsers such as `lynx`.

Comment: Can we inStall Linux on a ROM of a device?